# JQueryUI dialog moving outside browser window

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using JQueryUI with dialogextend on a boostrap template (Shards UI).

I have the issue that the dialog can move outside the window and makes scrollbars to the webpage:

[image: Move Dialog beyond Window]

Does anyone know what can cause this? I've tried to include the CSS and JS in different orders, but that doesn't help.
Here is the minimal code on which the issue still appears:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">s
</head>

<body class="h-100">
    <div id="testdialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#testdialog" ).dialog({
      resizable: true,
      closeText: "",
      height: "auto",
      width: 400
    });
     $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index',9999);
  } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have two exampled, yet they do not seem right. Please take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and then provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I was using a different version of the JS file and CSS file. Using the same version works.